# Why can't I override settings in SBT subproject if it defines a Project value?

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I have a subproject that defines `root` like this:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

and doesn't define any other settings.

In my main project I reference it like this:

```
lazy val mylib = (project in file("mylib"))
lazy val myapp = (project in file("myapp")).dependsOn(mylib)
```

The problem is that referenced this way, `mylib` is built with Scala 2.10 because it doesn't specify a `scalaVersion` and 2.10 is SBT's default.

If I try to override any settings like this:

```
lazy val mylib = (project in file("mylib")).settings(Seq(scalaVersion := "2.11.8"))
```

they get ignored.

However, if I remove the `lazy val root = ...` from subproject's `build.sbt` the settings passed from the main build file work as expected. This breaks the subproject's standalone build however since the PlayScala plugin has to be enabled in the main file.

So how can I reference a project like that and override some settings?

I can work around this by changing the settings globally (i.e. `scalaVersion in ThisBuild`), but I would like to be able to override other things like the project id for instance which is fixed as `root` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I usually overrides settings like this, and it works fine.

```
lazy val mylib = (project in file("mylib")).settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
  //any other settings, I want to override, separated by comma
  propertyA := "A",
  propertyB := "C"
)
```

The difference is, I usually have dependencies in my Play application, but everything is listed under one build.sbt

Comment: Yup, that is what I was doing, however one of the projects I want to include is a submodule cloned from a github repo (which I would like to keep compatible with upstream) and it includes the lazy val root = ... line to enable the Play plugin. If it did not define a project it would work fine, but it does, and I can't override it's settings >.<

Comment: could you share sbt file that you're using, so it will be easier to reproduce